# Django - Can't load custom filter in templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to show delta time as 'x days ago'. I tried Django's timesince filter, but it returns 'x days, x minutes'. I want to show only days. I tried humanize's naturaltime, but I guess its only for DateTimeField. I'm using DateField.

I have a custom filter like this (app_filters.py);

```
from django import template
from datetime import date

register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='days_since')
def days_since(value):
    delta = value - date.today()

    if delta.days == 0:
        return 'Today'
    elif delta.days < 1:
        return '{} days ago'.format(abs(delta.days))
    elif delta.days == 1:
        return 'Tomorrow'
    elif delta.days > 1:
        return 'In {} days'.format(delta.days)
```

This is application folder;

```
app/
    models.py
    views.py
    ...
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        app_filters.py
```

I added the 'app' to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py
I'm trying to use this filter in templates like this;

```
{% extends 'app/base.html' %}
{% load app_filters %}

{{ entry.date_updated | days_since }}
```

Then I get the error: 'app_filters' is not a registered tag library.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Can you load the filter file from a shell? In `python manage.py shell` try something like `from app.templatetags import app_filters`. There's also the possibility that there's an error somewhere in app_filters.py and Django is not passing it down to you. Also, forgive the obvious question but did you try restarting the server?

Comment: No errors in `app_filters.py`, I just tried it and it works just fine. I did encounter the same error as you did but in my case it was because my `templatetags` folder was in the wrong place and thus was not being picked up even though the app was in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Could that be your case as well?

Comment: try creating your template tag folder in project directory.It will work as expected.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I realized that I need to restart web server to load custom template filters. This is the solution in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue: as well as restarting ensure that your filters.py classes are within INSTALLED_APPS for django else they won't be picked up.

> The app that contains the custom tags must be in INSTALLED_APPS in order for the {% load %} tag to work. This is a security feature: It allows you to host Python code for many template libraries on a single host machine without enabling access to all of them for every Django installation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags

Answer (score 0):

the issue might be with django itself cause it won't register the filters unless you restart the server.
It was pretty annoying for me as well.
Hope it helps